# How do i connect multiple ground wires? There are 3 green and 1 bare wire on my light fixture

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting

[image]
Fixture has 3 hanging lights, each light has 1 green, 1 white and 1 black wire.  There is also a bare copper wire on the base of the new fixture. How do i properly attach the green ground wires and the bare wire?

Comment: Is there some reason that's making you believe that you can't simply wirenut all the ground wires you've identified to the ground wire(s) coming from the ceiling box?

Comment: I was wondering the same, in the U.K.? Or some place home wiring not legal?

Comment: Use the screw in the bottom of the octagonal wire box on which the fixture is suspended. Use a small bit of bare copper to "pigtail" the three cables with a "marrette" wire nut, then attach that to the wire box.

Answer (score 1):

You can wire them the same way you'd wire the white wires together and the black wires together. If there's a green or bare wire coming out of the ceiling connect it to the group of ground wires too. Use standard wire nuts or something similar to the below illustration if in the U.K.
[image]